# Getting sudo and nohup to work together

Tags: linux, sudo, nohup

Linux newbie here.

I have a perl script which takes two command line inputs. I tried to run it in the background but this is what I got:

```
[~user]$ nohup sudo ./ascii_loader_script.pl 20070502 ctm_20070502.csv &
[2] 19603
[~user]$ nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'
```

after the system returns "nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'", no new prompt will appear. Then as long as I type in some other command, the shell will tell me that the process is stopped:

```
[~user]$ nohup sudo ./ascii_loader_script.pl 20070502 ctm_20070502.csv &
[2] 19603
[~user]$ nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'
ls
ascii_loader_script.pl  format_wrds_trd.txt  nohup.out  norm_wrds_trd.cfg
[2]+  Stopped                 nohup sudo ./ascii_loader_script.pl 20070502 ctm_20070502.csv
```

I've looked at this post and tried to do "sudo date" before executing the command. Still got the same thing.
http://www.sudo.ws/pipermail/sudo-users/2003-July/001648.html

Comment: May I suggest another solution? It is likely that you want to use `nohup` to protect the process from closing the terminal. If yes, you might be better off with `screen`.

Comment: suggested workaround: add `sudo echo hi` or something else to your `.bashrc` file, so you entered the password once right at the beginning

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem here, imho, is not nohup, but background processing sudo.

You are putting the process in background (&  at end of command) but probably sudo needs password authentication, and that is why the process stops.

Try one of these:

1) remove the ampersand from end of command, reply to passord prompt and afterwords put it in background (by typing CTRL-Z  - which stops the process and issuing the bg command to send it to background)

2) Change the /etc/sudoers to not ask for users password by including the line:
myusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

If besides the password reply your application waits for other input, then you can pipe the input to the command like this:
$ cat responses.txt|sudo mycommand.php

hth

Comment: Is it possible to stop further output after you've executed bg

Comment: `sudo mycommand.php <responses.txt` is better behaved than the `cat` approach. With the `cat` approach you're starting two separate executables (one of them `/bin/cat`); with `<responses.txt` you're _only_ starting `sudo`, and connecting its stdin direct to `responses.txt`.

Answer (score 57):

The solution is to use the -b flag for sudo to run the command in the background:

```
$ sudo -b ./ascii_loader_script.pl 20070502 ctm_20070502.csv
```

You should only use nohup if you want the program to continue even after you close your current terminal session

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I can do wonderfull things like `nohup sudo -b mongod`.

Comment: Wait but what if you do want the process to continue even after you close your current terminal session?

Comment: I would like to follow up on what @KurtWheeler said, what happens if you close your terminal?  And what happens to output from the command?  That is the whole point of nohup, that it is in the background, output goes to a file, and it doesn't stop when you quit the terminal.  Documentation on the sudo -b options leaves a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 11):

You can Try

```sh
sudo su
```

and then

```sh
nohup ./ascii_loader_script.pl 20070502 ctm_20070502.csv &
```

instead of

```sh
nohup sudo ./ascii_loader_script.pl 20070502 ctm_20070502.csv &
```

Comment: I think this is better than both the accepted answer and the highest voted answer. Neither of those actually address how to get nohup running with sudo.

Comment: This one served me the best!

Comment: My boss keeps doing this and it messes up so much stuff. He mainly uses Windows and just dabbles in Linux. Edit: because it changes your user rather than executes commands using your user with elevated privileges.

Answer (score 5):

You must use sudo first, nohup second.

```
sudo nohup ./ascii_loader_script.pl 20070502 ctm_20070502.csv &
```

Comment: For other readers, the command line shown here is not correct but the comment about order is. The ampersand will background sudo here rather than the command being run as sudo; use the -b flag to sudo instead like other answers mention.

Comment: Why?? What is the reason of using 'sudo' first?

Comment: Bumping the question above - please explain why this order is correct.

Comment: From that, I remember when I used nohup first it didn't work. I don't remember what was a reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can set it as your alias:

```
sudo sh -c 'nohup openvpn /etc/openvpn/client.ovpn 2>&1 > /dev/null &'
```

Answer (score 2):

My working solution for evaluating disk fragmentation in the background:

1. Exec **sudo** with **nohup** without ampersand (**&**) at the end:

```
  $ sudo nohup nice -20 find / -type f -exec filefrag "{}" \; | sed 's/^\(.*\): \([0-9]\+\) extent.*/\2\t\1/'| awk -F ' ' '$1 > 0' | sort -n -r | head -50 > filefrag.txt
```

2. Enter password for sudo;
3. Press **Ctrl+Z**;
4. Put the running process in the background.

```
$ bg 1
[1]+ sudo nohup nice -20 find / -type f -exec filefrag "{}" \; | sed 's/^\(.*\): \([0-9]\+\) extent.*/\2\t\1/' | awk -F ' ' '$1 > 0' | sort -n -r | head -50 > filefrag.txt &
```

5. Now you can exit the terminal and log in later. The process will remain running in the background. Because **nohup** is used.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
sudo -b -u userName ./myScript > logFile
```

I am just curious to understand that can I send this logFile as a email after the ./myScript is successful running in background.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should switch `sudo` and `nohup`.
And then:

```
if sudo echo Starting ...
then
    sudo nohup <yourProcess> &
fi
```

The `echo Starting ...` can be replaced by any command that does not do much.
I only use it as dummy command for the `sudo`.

By this the `sudo` in the if-condition triggers the password-check.
If it is ok then the `sudo` session is logged in and the second call will succeed, otherwise the `if` will fail and not execute the actual command.

Answer (score 1):

I open an editor and typed these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo echo Starting ...
sudo -b MyProcess
```

(Where *MyProcess* is anything I want to run as superuser.)

Then I save the file where I want it as MyShellScript.sh .

Then change the file permissions to allow execution.
Then run it in a terminal.  the "-b" option tells sudo to run the process separately in the background, so the process keeps running after the terminal session dies.

Worked for me in linux-mint.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
xterm -e "sudo -b nohup php -S localhost:80 -t /media/malcolm/Workspace/sites &>/dev/null"
```

When you close xterm, the `PHP` web server still alive.
Don't put `nohup` before `sudo` or else the `PHP` web server will be killed after closing xterm.