# nohup'ing a sudo command - doesn't seem to work

Tags: bash, background-process, sudo, nohup

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475098/getting-sudo-and-nohup-to-work-together) and several other articles but I can't figure this out. This is what I've put together:

1. `sudo nohup` or `nohup sudo` (I've tried both) the command without the background `&` (so you can enter your password before detaching it)
2. Enter the password
3. `^Z` then `bg`
4. `disown` the pid (doesn't work for some reason)
5. Log out

Here's the output:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ nohup sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
[sudo] password for user: 
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 nohup sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M
[user@localhost ~]$ bg
[1]+ nohup sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M &
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo ps | grep dd
 2458 pts/32   00:00:00 dd
[user@localhost ~]$ disown 2458
-bash: disown: 2458: no such job
[user@localhost ~]$ logout
Connection to [server] closed.
$ remote
Last login: Mon Feb  3 11:32:59 2014 from [...]
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo ps | grep dd
[sudo] password for user: 
[user@localhost ~]$
```

So the process is gone. I've tried a few other combinations with no success. Any ideas to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-b` option to `sudo` to instruct it to run the given command in the background. Job control doesn't work because the `nohup` process is not a child of the current shell, but of the `sudo` process.

```
sudo -b nohup dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using disown correctly, the right argument should be the jobspec ('%' + job number).

In your example you should have `disown %1` instead of `disown 2458`.

For listing your current shell jobs list, you can use the bash builtin `jobs`

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. I can `disown %1` and it disappears from `jobs` but the process is still gone after a logout. This happens whether or not I use `sudo nohup ...` or just `sudo ...`.